# How can I center my login/inquire buttons when on mobile displays?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a responsive website

[Link](http://www.voipstreet.com/testSite/index.html)

That changes the header when it goes below 450 pixels. 
It is going well except that I need my inquire and log in buttons to center when below 450 pixels.

Screenshot of buttons for reference

[Buttons Highlighted in yellow](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66131799/screenshots/voipMobileNavigationButtons.jpg)

I tried

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

and

```
text-align:center;
```

This didn't work. So instead, I gave both icons a

```
margin-left: 40px;
```

This worked, on android phones. On iPhones, it broke to two lines.

I don't have a screenshot of this but you can see the effect

[Here](http://iphone4simulator.com/www.voipstreet.com/testSite/index.html)

Here is my

CSS

```
#headerIcons img{
   float:right;
   margin-top:30px;
   margin-right:10px;
}

/*Float icons right on medium sized screens*/
@media all and (min-width: 628px) and (max-width: 989px){
    #headerIcons img{
        display:block;
        float:right;
        margin-left:15px;
        margin-top:10px;
    }
} 

/*float left again for tablets*/
@media all and (min-width: 451px) and (max-width: 627px){
    #headerIcons img{
        display:block;
        float:left;
        margin-left:3px;
        margin-top:10px;
    }
} 

/*Center for phones*/
@media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 450px){
    #headerIcons img{
        display:block;
        float:left;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-left:40px;
    }
}
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div class="d10-d12 m-1" id="headerIcons">
    <img id="loginIcon" src="images/new_logoin_vi.jpg" width="116" height="37">
    <img id="inquireIcon" src="images/new_inquire_button_vi.jpg" width="116" height="37" >            
</div>
```

Comment: try `text-align: center`

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I tried this already. It did not work. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `display: inline-block` & removing the float; you should then be able to use `text-align: center;` or `margin: auto;` on the containing div.

Comment: I will accept this answer. However, the issue was that the float:right; was carrying over from the previous media queries. Once i added a float:none to the bottom one, it fixed my issues.

Comment: Yep; that's why I said to try removing the float. Glad it helped.

Answer (score -1):

I checked and you need this :

```
 text-align: -webkit-center;
```